# Store and retrieve data from local storage using chrome storage API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am in process of building an extension, the extension displays a value in seconds to the user as for the amount of time user has spent on a particular website. I have got everything working but every time chrome is quitted or the computer is restarted the time variable starts counting again from 0. I figured using chrome storage API should do the job. After going through the API documentation I managed to store and retrieve a number from the local storage. What I can't do is how to save the data to the local storage when user quits chrome. Is there a way to detect such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use the `chrome.storage` API to make this work. By the way, unfortunately, what you're looking for does not exist. You are looking for some event (like `onBrowserClosed`) that isn't implemented in the Chrome APIs. A bug report has been made **[HERE](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885)** (although it actually isn't a bug), if you want to stay updated you can star it.

Although, you can still approach the problem with a `setInterval()`, that will execute your function to update the time a user has spent on a site every certain interval (in milliseconds), and will stop when the browser is closed. Something like this:

```
var currentActiveTab, chromeHasFocus = false;

localStorage.timeSpentOnSites = localStorage.timeSpentOnSites || "{}";

// get the first tab at startup
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, highlighted: true}, function(tabs) {
    currentActiveTab = tabs[0];
    console.log('New active tab:', tabs[0]);
});

// this will keep currentActiveTab updated to always be the active tab (the one that the user is watching)
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID, info, tab) {
    if (tab.active && tab.highlighted) currentActiveTab = tab;
    console.log('New active tab:', tab);
});

// this also
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, highlighted: true}, function(tabs) {
        currentActiveTab = tabs[0];
        console.log('New active tab:', tabs[0]);
    });
});

// this will check if chrome is active or not
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowID) {
    if (windowID === chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
        chromeHasFocus = false;
        console.log('Chrome lost focus.');
    } else if (!chromeHasFocus) {
        chromeHasFocus = true;
        console.log('Chrome has focus.');
    }
});

function addTimeSpentOnSite(site) {
    var T = JSON.parse(localStorage.timeSpentOnSites);

    // if site already exists increment the time spent on it
    if (T[site]) T[site]++;
    // otherwise set the time spent on it as 1 (second)
    else T[site] = 1;

    localStorage.timeSpentOnSites = JSON.stringify(T);
}

setInterval(function() {
    if (!chromeHasFocus) return;
    // if the chrome window isn't active the user is not watching the site

    var site = currentActiveTab.url.split('/')[2]; 
    // get the site name, something like www.site.com

    addTimeSpentOnSite(site);
    // increase the amount of time spent on the site
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, that it's exactly what I ended up doing. But isn't it inefficient?

Comment: @nashmaniac yes, I know, it's a little inefficient, and setting a smaller amount of milliseconds in setInterval will make it work slower, but it's the only solution right now.